# Failed opening required 'Zend/Config/Exception.php'

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server-ce

I've been working on this project for about two weeks now. I don't understand why now I receive this error:

> **Warning**: require_once(Zend/Config/Exception.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/zendsvr/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php **on line** 180
>
> **Fatal error**: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Config/Exception.php' (include_path='/www/zendsvr/htdocs/TassiWeb/application/../library:/www/zendsvr/htdocs/TassiWeb/library:.:/usr/local/zendsvr/share/ZendFramework/library:/usr/local/zendsvr/share/pear') in /usr/local/zendsvr/share/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Config/Ini.php **on line** 180

I'm using ZendServer CE into IBMi but others web-application works correctly!
How can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the requested file exist in your Zend Framework folder? The include path etc seem to be correct, so it may just be an accidentally deleted file...

Comment: i think that receive error in Bootstrap.php at this function  function _initSetLibrerie(){
  $config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/www/zendsvr/htdocs/TassiWeb/application/configs/application.ini', 'production'); 
  Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
 }

Comment: Since it's a Config Exception being raised, I expect that there's an error in your config file but it isn't being handled correctly. If you make sure you have the correct file in your Zend Framework, then the exception will be handled and logged better and you can find out what the REAL error is ;)